# 403 Error when serving swf files from Service Stack on IIS

Tags: iis, flash, servicestack, http-status-code-403

I am trying to serve a swf file from a web app that uses Service Stack. When requesting the swf file I get a 403 response (see below). I don't encounter this problem serving any other static files from this application (html, css, js, xap, jpg, png, etc...)

The same behavior occurs when debugging in Visual Studio as well as when the site is deployed to IIS.

Has anyone else run into similar issues?

Here is the response from the server:

```
Forbidden

Request.HttpMethod: GET
Request.PathInfo: 
Request.QueryString: 
Request.RawUrl: /swf/plupload/plupload.flash.swf
App.IsIntegratedPipeline: False
App.WebHostPhysicalPath: C:\Users\me\Documents\GitHub\Project\src\Project.Host.Web
App.WebHostRootFileNames: [project.host.web.csproj,project.host.web.csproj.user,apphost.cs,customusersession.cs,default.html,global.asax,global.asax.cs,packages.config,plupload.flash.swf,web.config,web.debug.config,web.release.config,app_data,bin,css,img,js,logs,obj,properties,swf,xap]
App.DefaultRootFileName: default.html
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ServiceStack includes a whitelist so only files with well known extensions get served by default. You can add **.swf** to the whitelist by adding it in your AppHost.Configure():

```
SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig {
    AllowFileExtensions = { {"swf"} },
});
```